# Make <img> tag tabbable - respond to TAB key navigation

Tags: html, css, image

I have an IMG tag which has an associated OnClick event.

I see that TAB-key navigation skips this image field, but I need to have it stop there and treat the element as a regular tabbable control field.

Is there a way to do this? I can't just wrap a simple A-tag around it, since that affects various stylesheets and breaks the design.

Comment: not sure about it, but try adding `tabindex="0"` attribute to it. But then, it might mess up the order of tab shifts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the best approach is to use a button instead, and bind the click event to that.

```
<button type="button"><img src="..." alt="..."></button>
```

You can also stick `tabindex="0"` onto the image so that it will appear in the tab order (without specifying a specific place so the ordering is natural), but this doesn't give as good results with AT.